# JS verify login form - where I went wrong?

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, authentication

I have nut to crack, that cracks my head for some time now.

I'm programming beginner, that's for introducing. I try to achieve JS form validation, that checks input fields `email` and `password` and if it match some criteria, unset `"disabled"` attribute on login button.

I tried components of my JS code and it works just fine, but when I merge it into function `validate()`, it just dont works and I cannot find reason why.

Here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <meta charset='UTF-8' />
  <title>$title</title>
  <link href='css/style.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
  <script type='text/javascript' charset='utf-8' src='js/validateInput.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id='header'><h1>$title<h1></div>
  <form name='login' method='post' action=''>
    <table border='0'>
      <tr>
        <th>E-mail:</th>
        <td colspan='2'><input type='text' name='email' id='email' size='30' value='$posted_email'
     onkeyup='validate()' onclick='validate()' onchange='validate()' />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Heslo:</th>
        <td><input type='password' name='pword' id='pword' size='21'
          onkeyup='validate()' onclick='validate()' onchange='validate()'/></td>
        <td><input type='submit' name='login' class='submit' id='loginBtn' value='OK' /></td>
      </tr>    
    </table>
  </form>
</body>
```

Now my JS:

```
function $(id) {
  if (id.indexOf('#') == 0 || id.indexOf('.') == 0) {
    var name = id.substr(1);
    return id.indexOf('#') == 0 ? document.getElementById(name) : document.getElementsByClassName(name);
  }
  return (typeof document.getElementById('id') !== 'undefined') ? document.getElementById(id) : document.getElementsByClassName(id);
}
function validateEmail(string) {
  var re = /[\w\s\.\$\*\+\/\?\^\{\|\}\(\)]{1,64}@[\w]{1,250}\.[\w]{2,3}/;
  return re.test(string);
}

function validate() {
  var login = $('#loginBtn');
  var email = $('#email');
  var pword = $('#pword');
  if (!validateEmail(email.value)) {
    email.style.color = 'orange';
  } else if (pword.length > 0) {
    login.disabled = false;
  }
  return false;
}
window.onload = function() {$('#loginBtn').disabled = true;};
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: If Form Validation is only that you need, you can use HTML5 form validation  http://codeforbrowser.com/blog/html5-form-validation/

Comment: @defau1t Thanks for suggestion, but as far as I know, `required` attribute is not widely adopted (mainly by IE) and not standardized enough. Also, I want my form to be more user-friendly, so it will interacts with user as he types, not only after submit. But html5 `required` could be good fallback, if user has JS disabled, although it will never fully substitute server side validation.

Comment: Agreed, coming to your question. Are you pulling any values from php? what is $title and $posted_email in your form

Comment: @defau1t `$title` and `$posted_email` are the only two values, that I insert in this html code by PHP. `$title` is title and header of page `($title ='login')` and `$posted_email` is empty string or if user clicks submit button and fails to log-in, it contains previously submited email value `($posted_email = isset($_POST('email')) ? $_POST('email') : '')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is located at this condition :

```
  if (!validateEmail(email.value)) {
    email.style.color = 'orange';
  } else if (pword.length > 0) {
    login.disabled = false;
  }
```

Change your function validate() to below :

```
function validate() {
    var login = $('#loginBtn');
    var email = $('#email');
    var pword = $('#pword');
    var result = false;

    if (!validateEmail(email.value)) {
        email.style.color = 'orange';
    } else {
        email.style.color = 'black';
        result = true;
    }
    if (result && pword.value.length > 0) {
        login.disabled = false;
    } else {
        login.disabled = true;
    }
}
```

[Fiddle demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/dirgagautama/aQ6dX/)

Hopefully this help.

Comment: thanks, that works like a charm. I've got another problem with browser form autofill, which don't trigger any event and login button keeps disabled. I followed [this article about Capruting AutoFill as a Change Event](http://furrybrains.com/2009/01/02/capturing-autofill-as-a-change-event/) and it's all right now. Thank you again!